# Can't target this class in my CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I can't seem to target this class for my web app. I am using Twitter Bootstrap and would like to target my Start Over nav link and change Twitters default color on it. Any ideas? I've tried so may pseudo elemnts but I can't find the right one.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="/new_player">Start Over</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well there are a lot of ways to access that particular element, but without context we can't really tell you how much specificity you would need to override other styles that are being placed on it. Do you have a live example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the best and easiest way would be to give your element an id and target it with the id selector:

`<a href="/new_player" id="startOver">Start Over</a>`

```
#startOver{
     color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes a lot more sense then what I was trying to do, so simple. Thanks to the both of you

Comment: If this is your solution you should mark the answer as correct :)